# The Little Typer. I don't understand the meaning of The Initial Second Commandment of λ

Tags: racket, lambda-calculus, type-theory, pie-lang

I have tried following examples, but no matter y occurred or not,
The function f returns the same value as (λ(y)(f y)) after application.

I would like to do is to define a function that is not the same (-> Y X) as (λ (y)(f y)) when y occurred in y as a counter example, but I don't know how.

Do I misunderstand the meaning of The Initial Second Commandment of λ?

```
 

;;y does not occurs
(claim f (-> Nat Nat))
(define f
  (λ(y)
    0))

;; both return (the Nat 0)
(f 5)
((the (-> Nat Nat)
   (λ(y)
     (f y)))
  5)


;; y occurs
(claim g  (-> Nat Nat))
(define g
  (λ(y)
    y))

;;both return (the Nat 5)
(g 5)
((the (-> Nat Nat)
   (λ(y)
     (g  y)))
  5)
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly or if this helps in any way, but notice that `(λ (y) (f y))` is effectively equivalent to `f` since when you apply `((λ (y) (f y)) 5)`, you get `(f 5)`, which is the same as applying `f` to 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create an example illustrating the importance of the caveat "...as long as `y` does not occur in `f`", we need to create a function `f` in which a name `y` occurs *free*. The provision that `y` is *free* in `f` is critical. This is also why it is difficult to create such an example: (top-level) functions cannot contain free variables. However, functions that are *interior* to other functions can. This is the key.

Here is function `g` that contains another function inside of it:

```
(claim g (-> Nat
           (-> Nat
             Nat)))
(define g
  (lambda (y)
    (lambda (x)  ;; Call this inner
      y)))       ;; function "f"
```

(I've chosen to write the claim in this way to emphasize that we are thinking about a function inside of a function.)

To get our bearings, this simple function `g` expects two `Nat` arguments, and returns the first.

Let's call the inner function `f`. Note that `f` contains a free variable `y` (for this reason, `f` is meaningless outside of `g`). Let's substitute `(lambda (y) (f y))` for `f`:

```
(claim g1 (-> Nat
            (-> Nat
              Nat)))
(define g1
  (lambda (y)
    (lambda (y)     ;; Here we've replaced "f"
      ((lambda (x)  ;; with an eta-expanded
         y)         ;; version, introducing
       y))))        ;; the name "y"
```

We can eliminate the application to produce the following expression:

```
g1
---------------- SAME AS
(lambda (y)
  (lambda (y)
    ((lambda (x)
       y)
     y)))
---------------- SAME AS
(lambda (y)
  (lambda (y)
    y))
---------------- SAME AS
(lambda (y)
  (lambda (y1)
    y1))
```

In the last step, I've renamed the second `y` to `y1` to illustrate that the variable in the body of the inner function refers to the closer binding site, and not the farther one.

To recap, we started with a function `g` that "takes two (curried) arguments and returns the *first*". We then introduced a faulty eta-expansion around the inner function. As a result, we ended up with a function `g1` that "takes two (curried) arguments and returns the *second*". Clearly not equivalent to the original function `g`.

So this commandment is about variable capture, which is the price we pay for working with names. I hope that helps!

IMPORTANT NOTE:

Due to the way that Pie checks types, you will need to introduce an annotation in the body of `g` if you want to try this example out:

```
(claim g1 (-> Nat
            (-> Nat
              Nat)))
(define g1
  (lambda (y)
    (lambda (y)
      ((the (-> Nat Nat)
         (lambda (x)
           y))
       y))))
```